# How to insert a dictionary value into Tkinter Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, can-bus

I'm working on a program to decode can bus error messages. These messages are read into a dictionary accurately, but I've had trouble getting them to display in a treeview.  I've read the insert method and looked up countless examples but the mixture of dictionaries and treeviews has confused me.  Here's a small test program, what am I doing wrong in my insert statement?

```
from tkinter import *
from collections import OrderedDict
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk

GuiWindow = Tk()

TestDict = OrderedDict()

TestDict["MsgID"] = 1
TestDict["OtherData"] = 2

Errortree = ttk.Treeview(
    GuiWindow,
    columns=('Message ID', 'Other Data'))
Errortree.heading('#0', text='Message ID')
Errortree.heading('#1', text='Other Data')
Errortree.column('#0', stretch=YES)
Errortree.column('#1', stretch=YES)


treeview = Errortree

def TreeInsert():
print(TestDict)

Errortree.insert("", 'end', TestDict['MsgID'], TestDict['OtherData'])

scanvar = BooleanVar()

scanbtn = Checkbutton(
    GuiWindow,
    text="scan",
    variable=scanvar,
    command=TreeInsert,
    indicatoron=0)

Errortree.grid(row=0, columnspan=5, sticky='nsew')

scanbtn.grid(row=1, column=0)

GuiWindow.geometry('{}x{}'.format(400, 300))
GuiWindow.mainloop()
```

I do realize I have a double import but it's to get pylint off of my back for the verifiable example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this part of code

```
Errortree.insert("", 'end', TestDict['MsgID'], TestDict['OtherData'])
```

with this

```
Errortree.insert("", 'end', values=(TestDict['MsgID'], TestDict['OtherData']))
```

You need to insert your data in the `treeview` as a `tuple` so i converted your `dic` value to `tuple`

> Errortree.insert("", 'end', values=(TestDict['MsgID'], TestDict['OtherData']))

**full code**

```
from tkinter import *
from collections import OrderedDict
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk

GuiWindow = Tk()

TestDict = OrderedDict()

TestDict["MsgID"] = 1
TestDict["OtherData"] = 2

Errortree = ttk.Treeview(GuiWindow,columns=('Message ID', 'Other Data'),show="headings")
Errortree.heading('#1', text='Message ID')
Errortree.heading('#2', text='Other Data')
Errortree.column('#1', stretch=YES)
Errortree.column('#2', stretch=YES)




def TreeInsert():

    print(TestDict)

#Errortree.insert("", 'end', TestDict['MsgID'], TestDict['OtherData'])
Errortree.insert("", 'end', values=(TestDict['MsgID'], TestDict['OtherData']))

scanvar = BooleanVar()

scanbtn = Checkbutton( GuiWindow,text="scan",variable=scanvar,
command=TreeInsert,indicatoron=0)

Errortree.grid(row=0, columnspan=5, sticky='nsew')

scanbtn.grid(row=1, column=0)

GuiWindow.geometry('{}x{}'.format(400, 300))
GuiWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: if you have any question can ask

Comment: If you've got the time: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018048/tkinter-treeview-insert-issue-with-can-bus-message-collecting-in-python